# SQL Server can't get current incremented row from table variable

Tags: sql-server

I am running into a problem getting my recursive script to find the current row from a table variable.  I have verified that there is data in the table variable.  That part is working great, however the next part of my script keeps hitting my else statement.  It worked great with temp tables but I am trying to get this into a function so I can call it easier with other scripts.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @totalrows INT
DECLARE @currentrow INT = 1
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (value VARCHAR(255), ID INT)

SELECT * Into #temp FROM dbo.fn_split((SELECT TOP (1) address_full FROM sde.gis.BUSINESS), ' ') 



ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD ID INT IDENTITY


INSERT into @tempTable ( value, ID )
SELECT *
FROM #temp

SELECT * FROM @tempTable

DECLARE @address_no MONEY
DECLARE @pre_dir VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @street_name VARCHAR(45)
DECLARE @suffix VARCHAR(20)     


WHILE ( @currentrow <= @totalrows )
    BEGIN




        DECLARE @cur_value VARCHAR(50)



        SELECT  @cur_value = value
        FROM    @tempTable
        WHERE   id = @currentrow



        PRINT 'Working on ' + @cur_value



        IF ( @currentrow = 1 )
            BEGIN

                IF ( ISNUMERIC(@cur_value) = 1 )
                    SET @address_no = CAST(@cur_value AS MONEY)
                ELSE
                    RETURN
          END





        IF ( @currentrow = 2 )   -- Is this a direciton
            BEGIN

                IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                            FROM    mead.dbo.street_direction
                            WHERE   street_direction = @cur_value )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @pre_dir = @cur_value

                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @street_name = @cur_value

                    END
            END


        IF ( @currentrow > 2 )   -- Is this a direciton
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                            FROM    mead.dbo.street_type
                            WHERE   street_type = @cur_value )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @suffix = @cur_value



                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        IF ( @street_name IS NULL )
                            SET @street_name = @cur_value
                        ELSE
                            SET @street_name = @street_name + ' ' + @cur_value
                    END

            END

        SET @currentrow = @currentrow + 1

    END

END



SELECT  @address_no ,
        @pre_dir ,
        @street_name ,
        @suffix


DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: I can't see where you set the value of @totalrows

Comment: First, can you provide some sample data that reproduces the problem? Second, what do you mean it keeps hitting your else statement?  Which one?  Why do you expect something different?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to set the @totalrows and I meant to say it hits else statement for the if currentrow = 1

Comment: never mind I answered my question.  I missed the set value of totalrows to  @@rowcount.  I was blind apparently >< :)

Comment: It is always best to avoid looping in t-sql whenever possible. I don't see any reason in your code to use a while loop. Also, you have the dreaded fn_Split which is almost always a loop based string splitter. While your code may produce the desired result it could be exponentially faster if you get rid of the all the looping. I notice you also are using TOP 1 but there is no order by.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  Forgot to set my totalrows = @@rowcount.